# Android 13 or above android os pick image from gallery but gallery show me allow access button with black background how to fixed

Tags: android

I am unable to access storage when use android 13 or above OS device.[image]

how to fixed and able to access storage for android 13 or above OS.

Answer (score 0):

if you want open the gallery, i propose you use SSImagePicker library.